# In Angular, why am I forced to declare the provider before the config?

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

Why am I forced to declare the `provider` before the `config` function that will uses it?

In others words, this code works:

```
angular.module('app')
  .provider('testService', function() {
    // ...
  })
  .config(function(testServiceProvider) {
    // ...
  });
```

but not this one (got an `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testServiceProvider`):

```
angular.module('app')
  .config(function(testServiceProvider) {
    // ...
  })
  .provider('testService', function() {
    // ...
  });
```

(in my real code, these 2 blocks are defined in separate files, and thus the order of loading these files really matters)

My understanding was that when I call `module('app').config(...)` and `module('app').provider(...)`, the code is not executed immediately, but when the Angular application is bootstraped, and thus, that's the role of Angular to execute the differents code in correct order (i.e. the `provider` code and **then** the `config` code).

Thanks

ps1: I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118619/why-must-a-provider-be-defined-before-a-config-block), which is quite the same but the answer was more about suggestion or guessing...

ps2: I'm still working with Angular 1.2, maybe things changed with Angular 1.3 - 1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested on several Angular versions, and it appears to be a "bug" in 1.2.x version. Starting from 1.3.0 version, the order of the definition of the `provider` and `config` is not important.

- in Angular 1.2.29: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Lg3da4/ `-->` <kbd>KO</kbd>
- in Angular 1.3.0: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Lg3da4/1/ `-->` <kbd>OK</kbd>
- in Angular 1.4.8: http://jsfiddle.net/40arcz2p/ `-->` <kbd>OK</kbd>

test code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .provider('testService', function() {
    console.log('.. service');
    this.$get = function () {
      return {};
    };
  })
  .config(function(testServiceProvider) {
    console.log('.. config');
  });
```